# What are the origins of Qayin?

Tags: names, parashat-bereishit, etymology

[This article](http://www.bibleorigins.net/CainNimrod.html) is expressing that "Qayin" derived from the 1st millenium BC South Arabic word Qyn, and that Cain is not a name old enough in Bible times of the 2nd millenium. Is it plausible that this is in fact a correct approach?

**Passage:**

> Hess was able to identify qyn as an "administrator's title" in Old
>   South Arabic inscriptions, it appearing in Sabaean and Qatabanian
>   inscriptions of the 1st millennium BCE.  He also noted that epigraphic
>   sources for the Old South Arabian inscriptions do not exist for 2d
>   millennium BCE times. On the basis of the present evidence, Hess
>   concluded that Cain (Hebrew qyn) if derived from South Arabic qyn, (
>   qyn meaning a "metal smith" in later South Arabic) indicated that
>   Genesis' Cain could be no older than the mid-first millenium BCE.
>
> [....]
>
> A third suggestion derives from the lexica of Old South Arabic. This
>   is the qyn root used for the title of an administrator. The term
>   appears both in Sabaean and in Qatabanian. A root qyn has been found
>   in personal names in Old South Arabic inscriptions, including a qynw
>   who appears as a Qedarite ruler in a 5th century BC Aramaic
>   inscription from Tell el-Maskuteh at the entrance to Wadi Tumilat."

**and lastly**

> "Studies have placed Cain in particular geographical and chronological
>   contexts in the Ancient Near East. The figure of Cain has been
>   associated with the region south of ancient Israel, i.e., the modern
>   Negev and the Arabian peninsula. In part, this is because (as noted
>   above) the qyn root occurs in names of persons in South Arabian tribes
>   of the first millenium. It does not occur in the second millennium.
>   Both the geographical and chronological parameters on this name should
>   allow us to locate specifically in first millennium South Arabia."

Comment: Is this the most impressive piece of bible criticism you've ever seen that you decided to bring it here?

Comment: @user6591 Halevai that should be the most impressive piece of bible criticism... That website also contains "an irrefutable proof" against the divinity of the bible: David was made king despite being descendent from a Moabite

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this question deserves the close votes for the specific off-topic reason chosen -- it has to do with understanding the Torah. It is, however, based on many questionable assumptions, which is a reason to *downvote*.

Comment: Yanova -- I've lightly edited your question, to make it clearer which parts of the question belong to you, and which to your source. I've also removed a completely separate question about Nimrod, which had no basis in your sources. If you'd like to know about Nimrod, you may [ask a new question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 6):

> …that Qayin derived from the 1st millenium BC South Arabic word Qyn, and that Cain is not a name old enough in Bible times of the 2nd millenium. Is it plausible that this is in fact a correct approach?

No, it's implausible, as Cain lived well before that and even the Torah that mentions him was given us before that.

Answer (score 1):

The [Torah](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00760.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) clearly explains why Chava chose this name for her oldest kid:

> וְהָאָדָם יָדַע אֶת חַוָּה אִשְׁתּוֹ וַתַּהַר וַתֵּלֶד אֶת **קַיִן** וַתֹּאמֶר **קָנִיתִי אִישׁ אֶת ה'** ‏

"Chaya gave birth and called him Cain; [Hebrew for] I have created [Konithi] a person with Gcd".

Why would you think it's plausible that Chava named him something else? What would that name be?

If Arabic was *invented* 3,000 years after Cain was born, why would anybody think it's relevant to this discussion.